# How do I run a Python script through a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-webbrowser

I have a Python script called `test.py` with lots of functions and loops which outputs some raw data and I'm trying to run it from a webpage.

As an initial step I prepared a very simple code below using flask to see whether my script works or not.

I expected to render the output (some raw data) on the webpage but it seems it doesn't work for me, maybe I don't have a  good start for this.

In short, the thing I need is to enter to my server address and see the output of my script.

Yes if every thing is going well I will develop it to get input data too.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
import test
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def dynamic_page():
  return test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: import json at the top and return json.dumps(test()) in the dynamic_page function and see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

Berk, Flask's routes require certain type of responses (strings, tuples, Response instance, etc.) You can read about them [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses). I'm guessing your test function doesn't return any of those required types. 
What you can do is json-serialize the result of the `test` function and return that as a Flask response, and if that isn't possible (because of the kind of value `test` returns), then simply print it to the console. That way, you're still sure your function call worked. Look at the code below:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request

import test

# Also import json
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def dynamic_page():
   resp = test()
   try:
      resp = json.dumps(resp)
   except:
      print(resp)
      return "Function executed. Check your terminal"
   else:
      return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: It still can not run the script (test).

Comment: If it doesn't then what are you seeing when you visit the ```/``` endpoint? Are you getting an error? If yes, what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

What does `test` exactly do?

It looks like you're trying to call your module when user visits the route, instead, you should call a function.

If you want to execute a specific function when user visits your Flask route, you can do it like this:

```py
import test
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return test.my_function_here()

if __name == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This assumes that test is a module and not a standalone script. From the description in the question, test is a console script that just outputs some data.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim You're right, my bad!

Comment: Yes, test is a scipt including several functions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to call Python from your browser.

If this is the case you can just send an Ajax `GET` request to your route and that function will run.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/root/example/route/",
  method: "GET",
  success: () => console.log(`Python response: ${response}`)
});
```

Then add the following route function:

```
@app.route("/root/example/route/", methods = ["GET"])
def example_route():
  print("This was called from the browser!")
  return "All finished here!"
```

When you run the JavaScript in your browser Ajax sends a `GET` request to the Flask route which outputs:

```
This was called from the browser!
```

In your terminal, it'll then send:

```
All finished here!
```

To the browser where JavaScript will log it to the console.

**NOTE:** I assume you're using jQuery if not check out [youmightnotneedjquery.com](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194443/discussion-between-logicalbranch-and-berk).